fontspec 2.9b issue?
LuaHBTeX, Version 1.18.0 compiles the following file as expected with fontspec 2.9a.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\begin{filecontents}[overwrite]{MyLato.fontspec}
\defaultfontfeatures[MyLato]
  {
   UprightFont       = Lato-Regular.ttf ,
   UprightFeatures   = {SmallCapsFont={FiraSans-Regular.otf}} ,
   SmallCapsFeatures = {Letters=SmallCaps} ,
  }
\end{filecontents}
\setmainfont{MyLato}

\begin{document}
Some text \textsc{and SmallCaps}.
\end{document}

Output with fontspec 2.9a:

With fontspec 2.9b it tries to load Lato-Regular.otf instead of Lato-Regular.ttf the error message is:
Font \TU/MyLato(0)/m/n/10=[Lato-Regular.otf]:mode=node;script=latn;language=dflt;+tlig; at 10pt not loadable: metric data not found or bad.

and only small caps show up in the output, the regular text is "printed" in nullfont.

You probably want the filecontents environment before your \setmainfont, otherwise it might not get picked up on the first run.

Do you have both fonts installed or only the ttf?

looks like a bug. The otf extension spills over. Open an issue at the github.

@MarcelKrüger Thanks, I have corrected my example.

@UlrikeFisher issue reported right now at github.
